# Compile error when trying to install qjournalctl

Tags: software-installation, compiling, make

I am trying to install [qjournalctl](https://github.com/pentix/qjournalctl).

Before the install I did:

```
sudo apt-get install libxtst-dev build-essential libqt4-dev qt4-qmake cmake gcc g++ qt4-dev-tools libusb-1.0.0-dev
```

I downloaded the zip file and extracted it. I went into the directory and ran ./autogen.sh which did not report any errors. However when I ran make I got this. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/uic ui/mainwindow.ui -o ui_mainwindow.h
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/uic ui/aboutdialog.ui -o      ui_aboutdialog.h
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/uic ui/showbootlog.ui -o  ui_showbootlog.h
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB     -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -I/usr    /include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I. -I. -o     main.o src/main.cpp
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB  -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -I/usr /include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I. -I. -o  mainwindow.o src/mainwindow.cpp
In file included from src/mainwindow.cpp:10:0:
./ui_mainwindow.h: In member function ‘void    Ui_MainWindow::setupUi(QMainWindow*)’:
./ui_mainwindow.h:114:20: error: ‘class QTableView’ has no member named  ‘setSizeAdjustPolicy’; did you mean ‘setSizePolicy’?
      tableView->setSizeAdjustPolicy(QAbstractScrollArea::AdjustToContents);
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                setSizePolicy
./ui_mainwindow.h:114:61: error: ‘AdjustToContents’ is not a member of   ‘QAbstractScrollArea’
       tableView->setSizeAdjustPolicy(QAbstractScrollArea::AdjustToContents);
                                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/mainwindow.cpp: In member function ‘void   MainWindow::on_tableView_doubleClicked(const QModelIndex&)’:
src/mainwindow.cpp:141:64: warning: unused parameter ‘index’ [-Wunused- parameter]
 void MainWindow::on_tableView_doubleClicked(const QModelIndex &index)
                                                            ^~~~~
src/mainwindow.cpp: In member function ‘void   MainWindow::on_tableView_clicked(const QModelIndex&)’:
src/mainwindow.cpp:172:58: warning: unused parameter ‘index’ [-Wunused- parameter]
 void MainWindow::on_tableView_clicked(const QModelIndex &index)
                                                      ^~~~~
Makefile:250: recipe for target 'mainwindow.o' failed
make: *** [mainwindow.o] Error 1
```

Comment: You could want to try packaged log manager - GNOME Logs (`sudo apt-get install gnome-logs`).

Comment: Alas it says gnome-logs is already the newest version.

Comment: This means you may simply start it by `gnome-logs` command. I understand that it is substitution of original problem. Which Ubuntu version do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Note: Kudos to @N0rbert for reporting this as an issue!

(See: https://github.com/pentix/qjournalctl/issues/10)

## Update

I've just added an option such that it should automatically try to compile for C++11 which should then fix your problem. Try downloading the new zip file (of the master branch) and try compiling it again! ;)

## Workaround until I can publish a fix:

At the first sight it seems as if g++ does not automatically compile for C++11 (that's why it suggests to use the `-std=c++11`. Also the variable `nullptr` is defined when using the C++11 standard.

**As a first workaround**, you could execute `./autogen.sh` and then edit the `Makefile`. 
On approximately line 17 you should see something like

```
CXXFLAGS      = -pipe -O2 -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC $(DEFINES)
```

Add the flag there

```
CXXFLAGS      = -std=c++11 -pipe -O2 -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC $(DEFINES)
```

Then try again, running

```
make clean
make
```

It should compile fine then!

Comment: Thank you for fast response and fix!
I cloned master again, it compiles and runs on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, 16.04 LTS and 18.04 LTS without any user intervention. The way and quality of the solution to this problem can be considered a standard of interaction between the user and the developer, distribution and upstream!

Comment: @N0rbert Thank's a lot for testing this and reporting back! Great to hear it works!

Answer (score 2):

It seems that qjournalctl is based on Qt5, so we need to install it:

```
sudo apt-get purge libqt4-dev qt4-dev-tools
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get install qt5-default cmake gcc g++ build-essential
```

Then on 16.04 LTS I can compile version 0.21:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget https://github.com/pentix/qjournalctl/archive/v0.21.zip
unzip v0.21.zip
cd qjournalctl-0.21/
./autogen.sh
make
./qjournalctl
```

I can't compile 0.3, 0.4 and master because of compilation error:

```
...
src/mainwindow.cpp:61:24: error: ‘nullptr’ was not declared in this scope
   message_box.critical(nullptr, "Error", "No boots have been found :\n"+process.readAllStandardError());
...
```

I reported [bug #10 upstream to github](https://github.com/pentix/qjournalctl/issues/10) about this problem.
Note: `qjournalctl` compiles normally on 18.04 LTS (development version).